# Are there any other comparable implementations like commons-chain?

Tags: java, frameworks, jakarta-ee, apache-commons

I need simple workflow (not real workflow engines like jbpm or activiti etc) kind of library to be used for simple orchestrations. I am wondering if there are any out there. Main focus is on

1. Simple generified api with nested chain support
2. ability to execute chain or part of chain asynchronously
3. its own configuration based on xml so that i can persist orchestrations on DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing my own research, found that there is no framework out there that comes close to commons chain. There is however [one library](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/dp-chainofresponsibility.html) that seems interesting but doesn't fit my need.